# Divide certain columns by another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Was wondering if there is a more efficient way of dividing multiple columns a certain column.  For example say I have:

```
prev    open    close   volume
20.77   20.87   19.87   962816
19.87   19.89   19.56   668076
19.56   19.96   20.1    578987
20.1    20.4    20.53   418597
```

And i would like to get:

```
prev    open    close   volume
20.77   1.0048  0.9567  962816
19.87   1.0010  0.9844  668076
19.56   1.0204  1.0276  578987
20.1    1.0149  1.0214  418597
```

Basically, columns 'open' and 'close' have been divided by the value from column 'prev.'

I was able to do this by

```
df['open'] = list(map(lambda x,y: x/y, df['open'],df['prev']))
df['close'] = list(map(lambda x,y: x/y, df['close'],df['prev']))
```

I was wondering if there is a simpler way?  Especially if there are like 10 columns to be divided by the same value anyways?

Comment: Why didnt I think of that....lol thanks.  I knew I was doing it more complicated than it should be

Comment: `df.assign(open=df.open/df.prev, close=df.close/df.prev)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
df2[['open','close']] = df2[['open','close']].div(df2['prev'].values,axis=0)
```

Output:

```
    prev      open     close  volume
0  20.77  1.004815  0.956668  962816
1  19.87  1.001007  0.984399  668076
2  19.56  1.020450  1.027607  578987
3  20.10  1.014925  1.021393  418597
```

Answer (score 6):

```
columns_to_divide = ['open', 'close']
df[columns_to_divide] = df[columns_to_divide] / df['prev']
```

Answer (score 5):

For performance, I would suggest using the underlying array data and `array-slicing` as the two columns to be modified come in sequence to use view into it -

```
a = df.values
df.iloc[:,1:3] = a[:,1:3]/a[:,0,None]
```

To eloborate a bit more on the array-slicing part, with `a[:,[1,2]]` would have forced a copy there and would have slowed it down. `a[:,[1,2]]` on the dataframe side is equivalent to `df[['open','close']]` and that I am guessing is slowing things down too. `df.iloc[:,1:3]` is thus improving upon it.

Sample run -

```
In [64]: df
Out[64]: 
    prev   open  close  volume
0  20.77  20.87  19.87  962816
1  19.87  19.89  19.56  668076
2  19.56  19.96  20.10  578987
3  20.10  20.40  20.53  418597

In [65]: a = df.values
    ...: df.iloc[:,1:3] = a[:,1:3]/a[:,0,None]
    ...: 

In [66]: df
Out[66]: 
    prev      open     close  volume
0  20.77  1.004815  0.956668  962816
1  19.87  1.001007  0.984399  668076
2  19.56  1.020450  1.027607  578987
3  20.10  1.014925  1.021393  418597
```

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def numpy_app(df): # Proposed in this post
    a = df.values
    df.iloc[:,1:3] = a[:,1:3]/a[:,0,None]
    return df

def pandas_app1(df): # @Scott Boston's soln
    df[['open','close']] = df[['open','close']].div(df['prev'].values,axis=0)
    return df
```

Timings -

```
In [44]: data = np.random.randint(15, 25, (100000,4)).astype(float)
    ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=(('prev','open','close','volume')))
    ...: df2 = df1.copy()
    ...: 

In [45]: %timeit pandas_app1(df1)
    ...: %timeit numpy_app(df2)
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.68 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 885 µs per loop
```