# How can this iteration be applied to a dataframe to modify it?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The goal is to rename columns of a data frame based on a condition and modify the respective columns' values.

## Merge several data frames

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Mary', 'Mike', 'Barry', 'Scotty'],'eTIV': [1.12, 2.22, 3.43, 5.43], })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Mary', 'Mike', 'Barry', 'Scotty'],'Ear_Vol': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Mary', 'Mike', 'Barry', 'Scotty'],'Nose': [1, 2, 3, 5], })
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Mary', 'Mike', 'Barry', 'Scotty'],'Eye_Vol': [1, 2, 3, 5], })
df5 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Mary', 'Mike', 'Barry', 'Scotty'],'Finger': [1.3, 2.123, 3.4, 5.5], })

dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4,df5]

df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='ID'), dfs)

df_final

    ID      eTIV    Ear_Vol Nose    Eye_Vol Finger
0   Mary    1.12    5       1       1       1.300
1   Mike    2.22    6       2       2       2.123
2   Barry   3.43    7       3       3       3.400
3   Scotty  5.43    8       5       5       5.500
```

## Change column names

```
    df_final.columns = df_final.columns.str.replace(r"_Vol", "_Vol_Adj")
```

df_final_Adj = pd.DataFrame(data = df_final, columns= df_final.columns)
df_final_Adj

```
ID      eTIV    Ear_Vol_Adj Nose    Eye_Vol_Adj Finger
```

0   Mary    1.12    5           1       1           1.300
1   Mike    2.22    6           2       2           2.123
2   Barry   3.43    7           3       3           3.400
3   Scotty  5.43    8           5       5           5.500

Change values of columns which contain the header '_Adj'.

```
cols = df_final_Adj.columns[df_final_Adj.columns.str.contains('_Adj')].tolist()
print(cols)

['Ear_Vol_Adj', 'Eye_Vol_Adj']
```

Approach 1:

```
df_final_Adj[col] = df_final_Adj[col].div(df_final_Adj['eTIV'], axis=0)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'"
```

Approach 2:

```
for col in cols:
        df_final_Adj[col] = df_final_Adj[col].div(df_final_Adj['eTIV'], axis=0)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Can you give an example, I feel this would be much easier with an example. I am fairly certain you can do this without apply or iteritems, using only loc.

Comment: An example has been added to the edited version. But the actual data frame will be much larger, with different values, but same changes required.

Comment: Please can you paste the output of print(df.to_string) rather than use a screenshot?

Comment: Please supply example  of your source data. E.g. `df.head()`

Comment: Question edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the image shown in the OP is of the data **before** applying the function `eTIV_Adjust`, here is my attempt

Generate data per the OP description

```
d = [['one', 'two_Volume', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'four_Volume'],
    [1,1,5,1,5,5,5],
    [1,1,5,1,5,5,5],
    [1,1,5,1,5,5,5],
    [1,1,5,1,5,5,5],
    [1,1,5,1,5,5,5]]

df = pd.DataFrame(d[1:], columns=d[0])
print(df)
   one  two_Volume  three  four  five  six  four_Volume
0    1           1      5     1     5    5            5
1    1           1      5     1     5    5            5
2    1           1      5     1     5    5            5
3    1           1      5     1     5    5            5
4    1           1      5     1     5    5            5
```

Now, this line `if 'Vol' in key:` suggests you are looking for columns containing the partial string `'Vol'`. You can use [`.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to search for these columns without `iterrorws` or `.apply` (as @Andy Hayden suggested above) using this approach

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Vol')].tolist()
print(cols)
['two_Volume', 'four_Volume']
```

Now, just divide these columns by the column named `five` (see [this helpful SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45899667/4057186))

```
df[cols] = df[cols].div(df['five'], axis=0)
print(df)
   one  two_Volume  three  four  five  six  four_Volume
0    1         0.2      5     1     5    5          1.0
1    1         0.2      5     1     5    5          1.0
2    1         0.2      5     1     5    5          1.0
3    1         0.2      5     1     5    5          1.0
4    1         0.2      5     1     5    5          1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I modified the question in accordance with some comments to clarify. Your approach mostly works, however, I am having trouble with the last component that you suggested - see the last two error message within my modified question.

Comment: @arkadiy, check that your 2 columns containing `_Vol_Adj` don't contain strings in them. If indeed they're just supposed to be integers, then it sounds like you have a problem with datatypes. Try `df_final_Adj[cols] = df_final_Adj[cols].astype(int)` before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This approach works:

```
for col in cols:
    df_final_Adj[col] = df_final_Adj[col].div(df_final_Adj['eTIV'], axis=0)
df_final_Adj
```